# Sitecore MVC Form Post

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have a ControllerRedering and a view which shows news content and a partial view below that, which ables user to add a new comment.

```
    @using (Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("NewsContent","Index")

some controlls here...

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>

    }
```

and this is the controller content:

```
   public class NewsContentController : Controller
    {
            //shows news content
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = Factory.Context.GetCurrentItem<INews>();
            return View(model);
        }

           //saves comment
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Comment comment)
        {
            //get current item
            var parent = Factory.Context.GetCurrentItem<INews>();
            IComment _comment = new Comment
            {
                Description = comment.Description,
                FullName = comment.FullName,
                Name = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-ddThh-mm-ss")
            };

            var db = Factory.GetSitecoreService(Factory.SiteCoreDataBase.master);
            using (new SecurityDisabler())
            {
                db.Create(parent, _comment);
            }

            ViewBag.Message = "Thanks for comment";

           IView pageView = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.Current.PageView;
            if (pageView == null)
                return new HttpNotFoundResult();

            return (ActionResult) View(pageView);
        }
    }
```

After I click on add button, it says that

> A rendering has been recursively embedded within itself. Embedding trail: content-Controller: NewsContent. Action: Index [content-Controller: NewsContent. Action: Index- {04234ec6-d54e-4eb7-81df-402493d29c4f}] --> content-Controller: NewsContent. Action: Index [content-Controller: NewsContent. Action: Index- {04234ec6-d54e-4eb7-81df-402493d29c4f}]

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore throws this error if layout details or static binding cause a sublayout or rendering to bind to itself, resulting in infinite recursion.

I can see in your code - that your action do recursion to it self at the end.

```
IView pageView = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.Current.PageView;
            if (pageView == null)
                return new HttpNotFoundResult();

            return (ActionResult) View(pageView);
```

What you can do is just `return View("index");`

Comment: when I return View("Index"), Sitecore can not load complete layout. it just renders current page which has lots of DIV tags

Comment: which version of Sitecore you are using ?

Comment: Replace @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("NewsContent","Index") with this @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler() .

Comment: what if you add and else clause:
if (pageView == null)  { return new HttpNotFoundResult(); }
else { return (ActionResult)this.View(pageView); }